# SQL IN operator for multiple columns from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle 11.2 database and need the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.a_id AND (a.a_col1, b.b_col1) in ((?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?))
```

Please note, that the values don't matter, I am interested in the structure of such a query. I am going to execute the query from java, passing parameters.

UPDATE: well, it actually works. I hope someone needs this information one day...

Comment: Have you tried it? It's valid syntax in SQL.

Comment: You should also get used to explicit `JOIN`s instead of implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohhh, yes, my query actually works! I forgot some brackets when I tried it in TOAD. I wrote it correctly here!